# Why content in my page can't display?

Tags: wordpress

I edit a new page, here is the content.

[image]

Publish and view it.

[image]

Why is nothing displayed?
The theme is "twentyfourteen".

```
sudo cat /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen-child/page.php

<?php /* Template Name: Custom Front Page */ ?>

<?php
/**
* The template for displaying all pages
*
* This is the template that displays all pages by default.
* Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that
* other ‘pages’ on your WordPress site will use a different template.
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
* @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
*/

get_header(); ?>
<div id=”main-content” class=”main-content”>
<div id=”primary” class=”content-area”>
<div id=”content” class=”site-content” role=”main”>
<p>it is a test</p>

</div><!– #content –>
</div><!– #primary –>
<?php get_sidebar( ‘content’ ); ?>
</div><!– #main-content –>
<?php
```

Why are all the double quotation marks `”` instead of `"`, and single quotation marks are `‘` instead of `'`?

1. How do I get my page to display?
2. Are the quotation marks in the right format?

Comment: as per this template the dynamic content will not show the page will show "it is a test" and also check have you assign the template? when you edit the page in backend

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't print the content on the site. The best way do to this is to do it with the WordPress loop. So the code should look something like this:

```php
<?php </* Template Name: Custom Front Page */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
  <div id="main-content" class="main-content">
    <div id=”primary” class=”content-area”>
      <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php if(have_posts): while(have_posts): the_post(); ?>
           <h1><?php the_title(); ?>
           <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar( 'content' ); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

2. No it should be `"` and `'`